# Wireless options for connecting two buildings together (300ft)

Tags: switch, wireless, bridge

**Situation:**
Previous company setup each building on their own ISP/Modem. They then used cisco routers to create a VPN connection over the internet from the looks of it to the other building. This from my deduction has caused quickbooks to freeze and work horribly when trying to access the central server in building 2 at the bottom.

**Fix:**
What I want to do, correct me if this is the wrong way to go, is setup a wifi bridge by shooting a signal to each and connecting as so:

```
SWITCH<--->WifiBridge<------->WifiBridge<--->SWITCH
```

Is the going to be the correct way to go?

Also, what should I consider or look for when trying to determine hardware? My issue is they want this done ASAP and while I understand networking decently enough, I lack physical tools like ladders, drills, glue, ect... for doing serious professional mounting with polls like if I was going to mount a satellite dish. So I was wondering if maybe it would be enough to just mount or position the wifi bridge antennas in the comrooms high enough to shoot through the buildings roof and if that would be ok due to the short distant.

We ruled out running fiber or a CAT6 cable just due to all the concrete and hard labor that would be involved to properly run the line.

[image]

Comment: WiFi is one possibility, but I would also evaluate a laser shot; lasers are less vulnerable to interference compared to wifi

Comment: @MikePennington I will have to look into laser shot. That is a new term to me. Thanks.

Comment: What Mike is referring to is actually called "free space optics" or FSO.  It uses laser light between the buildings to send data.  It does require a direct line of sight between the endpoints.

Comment: One possible vendor:  http://www.mrvfso.com/

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title, as the ideal option would be to use a cable. In fact you're looking for other options since that is not possible.

Comment: My $0.02, avoid 802.11, it isn't designed for this use (much like using pliers to tighten a bolt...it will work, but not as well as a wrench).  Find a point-to-point technology designed for this purpose, like the suggested FSO or hardware working on a licensed frequency.  It will be more reliable and work better in more conditions.  Of course, you may find that it will cost nearly as much to implement/operate as a fiber run, with less flexibility to upgrade for more capacity (modern fiber should be able to support 10G and beyond when needed).

Comment: You really want to budget and implement single mode fibre in the long run. True you may save some money with the bridge setup but it will be your next bottleneck in the not too far future...Just my opinion from past experiences with the bean counters trying to save a buck that backfired afterwards.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ubiquiti, ubnt.com. A number of choices there that will work.

If you have a window in each building that has line of sight to the other window, you can place the wireless devices inside. I've seen that done with Hawking wireless bridges.

But, an external install would work best. Both Ubiquiti and Hawking's equipment is intended for outdoor install.

In either case you'll have to run cable to the antenna. Just placing it high in the building probably wont result in a decent signal. Those buildings probably have steel trusses and roof decking -- that's a tough environment for low-powered RF.

Are they too cheap to buy/rent ladders? Does no-one have tools?

And you already know the 'best' solution: run fiber between the buildings. (Edit: DO NOT run copper between the buildings -- lots of reasons -- lightning, ground potential, distance are some) I see some poles in the picture (parking lot lights?) -- those might/could be used for aerial cable between the buildings. Corning makes good aerial optical cable.

If you can't figure it out and/or install it, then hire a consultant/specialist. DON'T hire 'an electrician' -- they typically don't understand low-voltage and network requirements.